# Why would the emcee.EnsembleSampler.run_mcmc() function not vary my emcee.EnsembleSampler.chain values across successive steps for any of my walkers?

Tags: python, emcee

I am running the emcee.EnsembleSampler function in the emcee library to make markov chains of parameters for some research I am doing. For some reason some of the times that the run_mcmc function runs, the chains I find in the emcee.EnsembleSampler.chain object do not vary at all when they should be approximately gaussian in nature.

I have run this multiple times on some of my data, and it works perfectly fine, but in some cases it really just has the chains not iterate, just straight lines.

How I use the emcee code (works ~90% of the time):

```
sampler1 = emcee.EnsembleSampler(n_walkers, n_dim, self.__ln_prob, args = (event1, parameters_to_fit, parallaxType1), threads = 1)
sampler1.run_mcmc(start1, n_steps)
samples1 = sampler1.chain[:, n_burn:, :].reshape((-1, n_dim), order = 'F')
```

The __ln_prob function is written like this (with the functions used within it are also detailed here):

```
def __ln_prob(self, theta, event, parameters_to_fit, parallaxType):
    """ combines likelihood and priors """
    ln_prior_ = self.__ln_prior(theta, parameters_to_fit, parallaxType)
    if not np.isfinite(ln_prior_):
        return -np.inf, [-1, -1]
    ln_like_ = self.__ln_like(theta, event, parameters_to_fit)
    if np.isnan(ln_like_):
        return -np.inf, [-1, -1]
    if (parallaxType == 'positive') or (parallaxType == 'negative'):
        sourceFlux, blendFlux = event.get_ref_fluxes()
        if (sourceFlux[0] <= 0) or (blendFlux <= 0):
            return -np.inf, [-1, -1]
        sourceMag = MulensModel.Utils.get_mag_from_flux(sourceFlux[0])
        blendMag = MulensModel.Utils.get_mag_from_flux(blendFlux)
        return ln_prior_ + ln_like_, [sourceMag, blendMag]
    else:
        return ln_prior_ + ln_like_, [-1, -1]
```

The prior function:

```
def __ln_prior(self, theta, parameters_to_fit, parallaxType):
    """ priors - we only reject obviously wrong models """
    if theta[parameters_to_fit.index("t_E")] < 0.:
        return -np.inf
    elif (theta[parameters_to_fit.index("u_0")] < 0.) and (parallaxType == 'positive'):
        return -np.inf
    elif (theta[parameters_to_fit.index("u_0")] > 0.) and (parallaxType == 'negative'):
        return -np.inf
    return 0.0
```

I expect the chain values to oscillate, but they don't for some of the cases. No errors are thrown from my later code, so it seems like none of the -np.inf values return from __ln_prior or __ln_prob. The code should breka if -np.inf is returned I think? Maybe this is why?

I don't think the code is very necessary in understanding the issue, I just hope this must be some issue that comes up relatively frequently that I am clearly not understanding.

I tried looking through the source code for why the sample() function might return the same set of parameters that it received, but I don't seem to find this.

This is where the source code is found:
https://github.com/dfm/emcee/blob/master/emcee/ensemble.py